# Duda en el diseño de una aplicación con C++/Qt y Sqlite

Tags: c++, qt, diseño

Quiero desarrollar una aplicación con C++, con el framework Qt, y con Sqlite. Estoy desarrollando bajo Linux, pero la idea es que se pueda portar a Windows.

Mi prioridad es que los procesos se ejecuten lo más rápidamente posible. Ahora mismo no me preocupa el espacio de memoria (RAM o de almacenamiento).

Mi idea es que al iniciar la aplicación cargue la configuración de la base de datos y ciertos archivos. Según el número de configuraciones guardadas en la base de datos se generarán tantos hilos o "threads" de ejecución. En la práctica no serán más de 4 o 6. Estos se deben ejecutar de forma indefinida hasta que el usuario los cierre.

El crear tantos hilos como sea necesarios y poderlos detener y volverlos a iniciar lo tengo superado.

La complicación la tengo a la hora de procesar la información.

En la base de datos básicamente tengo cuantos procesos/hilos voy a tener que usar. Después para cada uno de los "hilos" voy a tener que usar X elementos de tipo A, tipo B, tipo C... En el siguiente hilo usaré Y elementos de tipo B, tipo C, tipo D ... El el siguiente hilo usaré Z elementos de tipo A, tipo D y tipo E. No se si me pilláis la idea...

Los "elementos" bien podrían ser objetos de una misma clase, o estructuras, con diferentes  datos de configuración (los tipos A, B, C, D, etc).

El número de elementos puede variar mucho. No se cuantos habrá hasta que procese la configuración al arrancar el programa. Lo normal será que no lleguen a 250.

Después en cada hilo tendré una configuración general y cada elemento tendrá su configuración propia según del tipo que sea.

El proceso irá elemento a elemento procesándolos según la configuración que tengan. Tiene que ser rápido el paso de un elemento a otro. Cuando llegue al último volveré al primer elemento para iniciar nuevamente el proceso. *Un requisito fundamental del proyecto es que sea lo más rápido posible*.

Actualmente quiero configurar los elementos que van a ir a cada "hilo" *ANTES* de crear el propio hilo. Así, cada elemento lo configuro una única vez para todos los hilos (en el caso de que existan elementos del mismo tipo en diferentes hilos).

Dentro de cada hilo habrán diferentes "objetos" que necesiten acceder a la información que contengan los diferentes "elementos". Esta es la parte que me marea un poco... ¿Creo los elementos con forma de estructuras de datos fácilmente accesibles o como objetos para interactuar con ellos?

Más preguntas: ¿cómo paso la lista de X elementos, Y elementos, Z elementos a cada hilo? ¿Con un vector de estructuras? ¿Con un mega-objeto que contenga X, Y o Z elementos? ¿Qué es más eficiente?

PD. Perdonad si no me he explicado muy bien. Estaré encantado de hacer cualquier aclaración que me pidáis. También pido disculpas si no he colocado la pregunta en el lugar correcto. No se muy bien donde encaja exactamente este tipo de preguntas en Stack Overflow en español.

Comment: Creo sinceramente que esta pregunta no va a obtener respuestas. Estás intentando abarcar demasiado terreno con una única pregunta. Prueba a reducir el ámbito de la pregunta, de tal forma que puedas poner algún ejemplo sencillo que ayude a entender el problema... Si no eres capaz de dividir tu problema en tareas más sencillas entonces va a ser prácticamente imposible que puedas terminar el ejercicio

Comment: Jajajaja y yo preocupado porque pensaba que había simplificado demasiado!!

Comment: Y de hecho tiene pinta de que lo has simplificado tanto que realmente no se termina de entender el contexto... pero aun así la pregunta sigue pareciendo demasiado amplia como para poder responderla... si no hubieses simplificado tanto te habría escrito un comentario similar

Comment: @eferion llevo un rato pensando en como concretar más la pregunta, pero con cada opción que se me ocurre elimino información que creo que es importante. Básicamente lo que estoy preguntando es:  *¿cual es la mejor manera de pasar un mogollón de datos a diferentes hilos teniendo que procesarla antes? ¿En formato structura o encapsulada en objetos?*

Comment: ¿Y cual es la diferencia? En C++ una estructura es lo mismo que una clase salvo por un detalle y es que su visibilidad por defecto es `public`. Para todo lo demás son exactamente iguales

Comment: Pues ya me has contestado a mi duda... ¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Añado un detallito que @eferion ha omitido, pero que es irrelevante para el caso: una estructura no tiene constructores ni destructores por defecto, ni hay funciones a las que se llaman cuando haces un `new`. En el resto de cosas, salvo gestión de memoria y procedimientos internos, se puede decir que sí, que son iguales.

Comment: A tu pregunta, @Jonathan, *¿cual es la mejor manera de pasar un mogollón de datos a diferentes hilos teniendo que procesarla antes?*, una de las maneras que me parece más limpia es serializando. De hecho, puedes desarrollar con TDD haciéndolo así, ya que al serializar objetos, los puedes guardar, exportar, importar y enviar entre hilos, procesos concurrentes o incluso procesos remotos, permitiéndote asegurarte que el estado obtenido es el que se espera, y el cómo se procesa, es el que se pretende. **Opinión personal**

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos lo siento pero tr equivocas. Una estructura sí que tiene un constructor y su respectivo destructor (si no los declaras son implícitos). Además también puede tener funciones miembro, herencia, funciones virtuales, sobrecarga de operadores... vamos, lo mismo que una clase al uso

Comment: @JoséManuelRamos y no veo qué tiene que ver TDD con la serialización. Puedes tener serializacion con XP, SCRUM, TDD o sin aplicar nada de eso... son cosas diferentes.